# Store records temporarily in a procedure as a type?

Tags: oracle, procedure

I am forming a dynamic SQL in my procedure like below to return  particular rows in a REFCURSOR :

```
/*
out_top_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

lv_query:='select '||lv_column_list||' from ( select /*+ first_rows(10) */ '||lv_column_list||', row_number() over (order by '||pk_column_list||' ) rn from '||lv_actual_table_name||' ) where rn in ( '||l_rownr||' ) order by rn ';    

OPEN out_top_cur FOR lv_query; 
*/


I derived the variable l_rownr in my procedure like below :

51,101,151,201,251,301,351,401,451,501

/*
FOR cntr IN l_min_page..l_max_page
LOOP

l_rownr:=l_rownr||','||(((cntr-1)*lv_page_cnt)+1);

END LOOP;

l_rownr:=LTRIM(l_rownr,','); 
*/
```

Each of this rownum indicate first row of a page being displayed. ( Each page displays 50 rows & calculated accordingly in the procedure .. in this case i know i have to display first record from page 2 to 11 )
Now although have the rownum , i need to send the page # along with each of these rows to the calling service .

Is it possible to hold the rownumber & page in some table type & then join in the final query ?
Can't think of any straight solution .. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a record and hold your temporary data in it.

Comment: I was thinking of using record type in the procedure to hold Page# & Rownum & then later reusing it , but doesn't look like record type can be joined easily later.

Comment: Create an object and then a table of object. It can be joined easily in a query. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/objects.htm